# How do I enumerate through a JObject?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to determine how to access the data that is in my JObject and I can't for the life of me determine how to use it.

```
JObject Object = (JObject)Response.Data["my_key"];
```

I can print it to the console doing Console.WriteLine(Object) and I see the data, it looks like:

```
{
 "my_data" : "more of my string data"
...
}
```

But I have NO idea how to just iterate/enumerate through it, anyone have any ideas?  I'm at such a loss right now.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `JObject`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), you will see that it implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>`. So, you can iterate over it simply using a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var x in obj)
{
    string name = x.Key;
    JToken value = x.Value;
    …
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but for reasons I don't understand, you can't use it with Linq unless you explicitly cast to the enumerable type.  I.e.  you  `((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>)obj).Select(...)` instead of plain-old `obj.Select(...)`; or at least that's what I found it one part of my code.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Is your obj declared dynamic? Extension methods (like Enumerable.Select) don't work with that.

Comment: No, in my case `obj` had type `JObject`; but `JObject` seems to have similar problems to `dynamic`.  The compiler can't infer the type arguments to `.Select`.  I can give them explictly, `obj.Select<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>, (result type)>(...)` also works for me

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Hmm, you're right. It's because `JObject` implements both `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>` and `IEnumerable<JToken>` (indirectly through `JContainer`).

Comment: Now how do I use it for nested JSON? For example, if the "value" contains another set of key:value pairs, how can I use the `JToken value` to iterate through next set of pairs?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala Try using the `Properties()` method on `JObject`. For example: `jObject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name + ": " + p.Value)`.

Answer (score 68):

[JObjects](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) can be enumerated via [JProperty](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm) objects by casting it to a [JToken](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm):

```
foreach (JProperty x in (JToken)obj) { // if 'obj' is a JObject
    string name = x.Name;
    JToken value = x.Value;
}
```

If you have a nested JObject inside of another JObject, you don't need to cast because the accessor will return a JToken:

```
foreach (JProperty x in obj["otherObject"]) { // Where 'obj' and 'obj["otherObject"]' are both JObjects
    string name = x.Name;
    JToken value = x.Value;
}
```

Comment: You can also conveniently use linq like so: `obj.Properties().Select(p => p.Name + ": " + p.Value)`.

Comment: This was exactly the information I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 20):

The answer did not work for me. I dont know how it got so many votes. Though it helped in pointing me in a direction.

This is the answer that worked for me:

```
foreach (var x in jobj)
{
    var key = ((JProperty) (x)).Name;
    var jvalue = ((JProperty)(x)).Value ;
}
```

Comment: With that (after this line: JObject priceComplianceJson = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(fullPath));) I get, "Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty'"
Removing the casting works, though: var key = x.Key;
                var jvalue = x.Value; - at least it compiles...I'll czech the functionality tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

For people like me, **linq addicts**, and based on  [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10543553/842935), here a linq approach:

```
using System.Linq;
//...
//make it linq iterable. 
var obj_linq = Response.Cast<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>();
```

Now you can make linq expressions like:

```
JToken x = obj_linq
          .Where( d => d.Key == "my_key")
          .Select(v => v)
          .FirstOrDefault()
          .Value;
string y = ((JValue)x).Value;
```

Or just:

```
var y = obj_linq
       .Where(d => d.Key == "my_key")
       .Select(v => ((JValue)v.Value).Value)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or this one to iterate over all data:

```
obj_linq.ToList().ForEach( x => { do stuff } );
```