# Iterate through JSON doc C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to create a simple app that takes a JSON document from the Google Maps API and iterates through it, showing each leg of the route, duration, and distance.

I have gotten it to display the first of leg, but I don't know how to make the boxes repeat. Maybe a foreach loop? I'm new and I'm really not sure.

```
var from = origin.Text;
var to = destination.Text;
var requesturl = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="
        + from + "&alternatives=false&units=imperial&destination="
        + to + "&sensor=false";
string content = file_get_contents(requesturl);
JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
string distance = (string)o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].distance.text");
string instructions =
        (string) o.SelectToken("routes[0].legs[0].steps[0].html_instructions");
txtDistance.Text = distance;
TextBox1.Text = instructions;
```

Comment: You can (and probably should) create an object that matches the JSON structure and deserialize the results into it. Then it will be clear how to iterate over it. Can you post the json you're getting back?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enumerate through a JObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543512/how-do-i-enumerate-through-a-jobject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer: [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) has code for some classes that let you deserialize JSON into a dynamic C# object. Sounds like it would be perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the entire JSON response and use objects to iterate over the results. This would be much more maintainable than hardcoding or calculating string paths.

You can take a look at [Google Directions C# wrapper](http://www.doogal.co.uk/GoogleDirections.php) for details

Answer (score 0):

As you have an example json document, you can create related contracts with http://json2csharp.com/. You can use your object with typed properties afterwards and easily iterate through related fields.