# How to create json schema from json object string C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

I am evaluating Json.Net.Schema from NewtonSoft and NJsonSchema from GitHub and I cannot figure out how to create a JSON schema from a JSON object.  I want it to work exactly like this site does: http://jsonschema.net/#/

What I am looking for

```
string json = @"{""Name"": ""Bill"",""Age"": 51,""IsTall"": true}";

var jsonSchemaRepresentation = GetSchemaFromJsonObject(json);
```

I would expect a valid JSON schema in the jsonSchemaRepresentation variable.  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What schema do you end up with in `jsonSchemaRepresentation` (i.e. what's wrong with it?)

Comment: The method is a made up method. I need to create a method that turns the json into its corresponding json schema.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I did not find a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of NJsonSchema [supports this feature](https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/SampleJsonSchemaGenerator):

> The SampleJsonSchemaGenerator generates a JSON Schema from sample JSON data.
>
> ```
> var schema = JsonSchema4.FromSampleJson("...");
> var schemaJson = schema.ToJson();
> ```
>
> ... or create a `SampleJsonSchemaGenerator` instance and call the `Generate("...")` method.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Actually **both of the libraries** you mentioned **do not support such a functionality**.

If you're down to implement it yourself then you will have to parse your JSON, [iterate over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543512/how-do-i-enumerate-through-a-jobject) recursively and [add a new schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonSchemaManually.htm) depending on the type of what you've just iterated over.

There are also some other tools (in other languages like python) which could be an inspiration, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341537/tool-to-generate-json-schema-from-json-data) might get you started.

Comment: Not correct, the current version of NJsonSchema supports this scenario: https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/SampleJsonSchemaGenerator

Answer (score 0):

The string you are submitting to the function is not in the correct format.  Try this (add '{' to the start of the string, '}' to the end):

```
string json = @"{
""Name"": ""Bill"",
""Age"": 51,
""IsTall"": true
}";

var jsonSchemaRepresentation = GetSchemaFromJsonObject(json);
```

Comment: Sorry, I misentered my string.  I have the correct string, thanks for posting this.  I have a valid json string and need a valid json schema from it.