# Is there possible to fetch json.net object like this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I have this json file and i want to work with each object.

[image: Json schema]

So foreach is on way but tried many of them even from stack and it doesn't fetch these objects to `i`.

Any ideas what went wrong?
I inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10543553/13122021)

```cs
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Paysami\Desktop\ccc\test.json"));
foreach (var i in stuff)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}\n", i.test1, i.test2, i.test3, i.test4, i.test5, i.test6);
    List<string> projectList = new List<string> { i.test1, i.test2, i.test3, i.test4, i.test5, i.test6 };
    foreach (var x in projectList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Paysami, it would be great if you create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please do not share code via image. Please amend your question to include the sample json. Please also try to rephrase your problem / question. It's hard to understand what do you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json doesn't contain any array and you can't use foreach to read that.
You should first deserialize your json to a class and then use deserialized data.

```
public class Json
{
    public JsonObject Object1 { get; set; }

    public JsonObject Object2 { get; set; }

    public JsonObject Object3 { get; set; }
}

public class JsonObject
{
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
    public string Test3 { get; set; }
    public string Test4 { get; set; }
    public string Test5 { get; set; }
    public string Test6 { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var staff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json>(File.ReadAllText(@"jsonPath"));

        var jsonObjects = new List<JsonObject> { staff.Object1, staff.Object2, staff.Object3 };
        jsonObjects.ForEach(jsonObject => Console.WriteLine($"{jsonObject.Test1} {jsonObject.Test2}"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use First:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\.json"));
foreach (var i in stuff)
{
   List<string> projectList = new List<string> { (string)i.First.t1, (string)i.First.t2, (string)i.First.t3, (string)i.First.t4, (string)i.First.t5};
   foreach (var x in projectList)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine(x.ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model/dto class with properties match with JSON and do the serialize/deserialize based on your request so that your data will be parsed correctly.