# Loop through a JObject and replace property value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hi I have a following JObject

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "CustomerApplication": {
    "contractDate": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
      "IsDBNull": false,
      "Date": "2020-07-05T00:00:00"
    },
    "lastTouchedDate": {
      "$id": "4",
      "$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
      "IsDBNull": true,
      "Date": null
    },
    "totalIncome": 110000,
    "createdByID": 0,
    "createdDate": {
      "$id": "5",
      "$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
      "IsDBNull": false,
      "Date": "2020-08-04T12:26:28.22"
    },
    "modifiedByID": 37683,
    "modifiedDate": {
      "$id": "6",
      "$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
      "IsDBNull": false,
      "Date": "2020-08-04T12:35:52.433"
    }
  },
  "Customers": {
    "$values": [
      {
        "custLicense": "555555",
        "custLicenseState": "TX",
        "dateOfBirth": {
          "$id": "11",
          "$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common.V4, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
          "IsDBNull": false,
          "Date": "1980-08-03T00:00:00"
        },
        "includeDebt": true,
        "customerNumber": "1234567",
        "phone": "1234578",
        "pager": "",
        "mobilePhone": " ",
        "memo": "",
        "residences": {
          "$id": "12",
          "$type": "Customer.Residence[], Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$id": "13",
              "$type": "Customer.Residence, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
              "residenceID": 265906636,
              "applicantID": 142874336,
              "applicationID": 110315632,
              "residentialStatusID": 0,
              "modifiedByID": 0,
              "modifiedDate": {
                "$id": "14",
                "$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
                "IsDBNull": false,
                "Date": "2020-08-04T12:26:36.953"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In my above json body, I have nested objects as shown in example below:

```
"contractDate": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
      "IsDBNull": false,
      "Date": "2020-07-05T00:00:00"
    },
```

So what I would like is to identify all properties which have type as follows

```
"$type": "Customer.DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter, Customer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f62344",
```

and flatten them to the "Date"  property value of that object like this:

```
 "contractDate" :"2020-07-05T00:00:00"
```

I want to  do this for all such properties at various nested levels of my Json object.
How can I achieve them..

---

this is what I have tried so far and works for most of my Jsons.

// When The Type is of JArray

```
JObject result= JObject.Parse(strStream);
                        var jsonObjItems = result["$values"];
                        JArray objArray = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(jsonObjItems.ToString());

                        
                        foreach (var item in objArray.Children())
                        {
                            JObject joItem = (JObject)item;

                            var lstNestedObjects = joItem.Children().Values().ToList().Where(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Object).ToList();

                            foreach (var newObject in lstNestedObjects)
                            {
                                var propValueType = newObject.Children().Values().Where(x =>
                                        x.Value<string>().Contains("DateTimeObjectDbNullConverter"))
                                    .ToList();
                                if (propValueType.Count == 1)
                                {
                                    var propName = newObject.Path.ToString().Split(".")[1];
                                    var propValue = newObject.Children().Values().Where(x => x.Type == JTokenType.Date).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
                                    joItem.Property(propName).Remove();
                                    joItem.Add(propName, propValue);
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }

                        result["$values"] = objArray;

                        return result;
```

But what I need is more like a generic method that can traverse through n number of Nested levels and change it . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a starting point for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543512/how-do-i-enumerate-through-a-jobject let us know if you have something and get stuck

Comment: Thank you Athanasios . Will check it up.

Comment: Hi Athanasios .. Please check what I have tried so far, I have updated my question with it.